Populate LWC HTML row based on JS results
I am trying to resolve 2 issues with an LWC

Render a calculated value in an LWC after the user inputs.  After the calculation, render value on correct row.  I can see the calculated value in console but never renders in html
Format for:each value.  I am only returning a single field value.  Right now it renders the value but cannot show label.  I would like the formatting to be similar to what I see using lightning-input

HTML
        <template if:true={laborTypeSpecific}>
            <lightning-layout-item size="12" large-device-size="2" padding="around-small">
                <lightning-input name="Days_Per_Crew__c" label="Days per Crew" type="number" value={row.Days_Per_Crew__c} onchange={handleDaysPerCrewChange} required></lightning-input>
            </lightning-layout-item>
            <lightning-layout-item size="12" large-device-size="2" padding="around-small">
                <lightning-input name="Number_of_Crew_Members__c" label="Number Of Crew Members" type="number" value={row.Number_of_Crew_Members__c} onchange={handleNumberOfCrewMembersChange} required></lightning-input>
            </lightning-layout-item>
            <lightning-layout-item>
                <template for:each={hourlyRate} for:item="hr">
                    <lightning-layout-item size="12" large-device-size="2" padding="around-small" key={hr.id}>
                        <div class="titleheadings">Hourly Rate</div>
                                <span>{hr.Hourly_Rate__c}</span>
                    </lightning-layout-item>
                </template>
            </lightning-layout-item>
            <lightning-layout-item size="12" large-device-size="2" padding="around-small">
                <lightning-input name="Labor_Total_Calculated__c" label="Labor Total" type="number" value={row.Labor_Total_Calculated__c}></lightning-input>
            </lightning-layout-item>

        </template>

JS
@api row;
@api projectid;
@track hourlyRate;

laborTypeSpecific;

laborTypeOptions = [];
@wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: ESTIMATE_ITEM_OBJECT })
objectInfo;

@wire(getPicklistValues, {
    recordTypeId: '$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId', fieldApiName: COST_TYPE_FIELD })
laborTypeOptionsWrapper({ data }) {
    if (data) {
        this.laborTypeOptions = data.values;
    }
}

connectedCallback() {
    getProjectHourlyrate({ paramProjectId : this.projectid })
    .then(result => {
        this.hourlyRate = result;
        this.error = undefined;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        this.error = error;
        this.hourlyRate = undefined;
    })
}

addNewRow() {
    const event = new CustomEvent('addrow');
    this.dispatchEvent(event);
}

removeRow() {
    const event = new CustomEvent('removerow', {
        detail: this.row.id
    });
    this.dispatchEvent(event);
}

handleLaborChange(event) {
    this.row.Cost_Type__c = event.detail.value;
    this.laborTypeSpecific = this.row.Cost_Type__c == 'Labor - Standard' || this.row.Cost_Type__c == 'Labor - Overtime';
}

handleCostTypeChange(event) {
    this.row.Cost_Type__c = event.detail.value;
}

handleDaysPerCrewChange(event) {
    this.row.Days_Per_Crew__c = event.detail.value;
    let numberOfCrew = this.row.Number_of_Crew_Members__c != undefined ? this.row.Number_of_Crew_Members__c : 0;
    this.row.Labor_Total_Calculated__c = this.row.Days_Per_Crew__c * numberOfCrew;
    this.handleChange();
}

handleNumberOfCrewMembersChange(event) {
    this.row.Number_of_Crew_Members__c = event.detail.value;
    let crewDays =  this.row.Days_Per_Crew__c != undefined ? this.row.Days_Per_Crew__c : 0;
    this.row.Labor_Total_Calculated__c = this.row.Number_of_Crew_Members__c * crewDays;
    this.handleChange();
}


The reactive property might not be updating as expected for the first issue regarding rendering a calculated value in an LWC. In LWC, to make a property reactive, it should be decorated with @track, @api, or be part of an object that is tracked.
Since the row is an @api property, changes to its nested properties won't trigger a re-render unless you replace the whole object or use the @track decorator on a private property.
Below is a modified version of your handleDaysPerCrewChange and handleNumberOfCrewMembersChange methods:
handleDaysPerCrewChange(event) {
   // Clone the current row to a new object to make the change reactive
   let newRow = {...this.row};
   newRow.Days_Per_Crew__c = event.detail.value;
   let numberOfCrew = newRow.Number_of_Crew_Members__c || 0;
   newRow.Labor_Total_Calculated__c = newRow.Days_Per_Crew__c * numberOfCrew;
   this.row = newRow; // Set the row to the new object to trigger reactivity
}

handleNumberOfCrewMembersChange(event) {
   let newRow = {...this.row};
   newRow.Number_of_Crew_Members__c = event.detail.value;
   let crewDays = newRow.Days_Per_Crew__c || 0;
   newRow.Labor_Total_Calculated__c = newRow.Number_of_Crew_Members__c * crewDays;
   this.row = newRow; 
}

You can wrap the value with a lightning-layout-item for the second issue and include a label element.
<template for:each={hourlyRate} for:item="hr">
   <lightning-layout-item key={hr.id}>
      <label class="slds-form-element__label">{hr.label}</label>
      <div class="slds-form-element__control">
        <span>{hr.Hourly_Rate__c}</span>
      </div>
   </lightning-layout-item>
</template>


Tushar.  The calculation is render now.  Thank you.  I updated the html above.  The only issue I am really seeing is the actual text Hourly Rate is lower than the the text.  Any thoughts?
